# <button type="submit"> with onclick submitting twice?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

I am currently facing some order duplication issues. Without going into too much detail, I had a question about the following. Is there any possibility that this can trigger a submit twice?

`<button type="submit" onclick="review.save()"></button>`

`review.save()` will handle the submission of the form - so in fact the type=submit isn't needed here. But I want to establish whether this CAN cause the browser to submit twice. On the server logs the 2 submits were about 10 seconds apart.

Comment: The browser does not submit twiche. It submits, when the button is clicked. What your function call review.save() does is on another page... ;)

Comment: Impatient users clicking twice maybe? Its a good idea to disable the button so as the users cannot click twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prevent default browser behaviour, for example:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="review.save(); return false;"></button>
```

Comment: or perhaps `<button type="button" onclick="review.save()">`? however can you confirm the original code IS the actual cause?

Comment: @FrancisKim: Yes, the code you have posted should also be sufficient since you are submitting the form within your `review.save`. A Submit button causes a submit action when the button is clicked and your `review.save()` is doing the other submit.

Comment: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JB844/) could be of help. The first and third buttons do only the click action whereas the second would perform the click action as well as the submit.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return false` to your Button or better the 'oncklick' event!

Like:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="review.save();return false;"></button>
```

It "stops" the default browser behaviour of following links (in that case).

Edit: To slow :/