# Will form submit twice if there's an onclick submit?

Tags: javascript

I've been [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789150/button-type-submit-with-onclick-submitting-twice) you need to add a "`return false;`" to the end of a method that submits the form.

I've tried the following code, and it appears though I omit the "`return false`" the form gets submitted only once, not twice. Does anyone know the standard browser behavior that dictates whether the javascript form submission overrides the html form submission or are they considered one action?

```
<form name="myform" action="">
    <button type='submit' onclick='submitForm();'>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>

function submitForm(){
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    document.myform.submit();

}
</script>
```

if I change the button to be an input type, I also get only one submission not two, from my tests, but I want to confirm this is the standard behavior.
i.e.:

```
<input type='submit' onclick='submitForm();'/>
```

Comment: No because your button is not a submit

Comment: Updated question. I get same result for input type submit

Comment: the only way it's not to set type submit for button and just submit via JS onclick event

Comment: If you want to submit it why add the `document.myform.submit();`? `onclick` happens before the submit so just remove `document.myform.submit();`, it'll then run your log, then submit.

Comment: When a form submits it refreshes the page.  Regardless of whether or not the script following would have submitted it twice, the page halts the execution in favor of the reload.  

Return false is effective when used in a script thats bound to the form's `onSubmit` property.  If the script is run in context of onSubmit, you may halt the execution (think validating form fields and intercepting submit for an empty required input).  Just returning false from a random function means nothing without it being in the context of the form submitting.

Comment: I think it'd help if you actually explained what your trying to do rather than asking odd questions that seem to be dancing around the subject.

Comment: @JamesLeClair so is your answer that the above code won't submit twice? It will submit just once?

Comment: @Liam I'm doing a code review of essentially the above code. I want to make sure it's "safe" in the absence of the "return false."

Comment: I tried to answer, could you try to check on your server-side code whether the document is sent once or twice ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments of the answer you linked, the fact is that `submit` will only submit the data in the form you handled, while the `onclick` attribute will trigger your method call, which triggers inside it another submit.

I think it acts as follow (feel free to correct me if I am wrong):

- You click on your button.
- Clicking triggered the `onclick` value, which will call your `submitForm()` method.
- Your method prints 'Button Clicked' in the console.
- Your document is sent a first time.
- Form is submitted a second time through its `submit` type.

That would explain why you see your `console.log` a single time. You would have to trace the result in your server-side in order to check if the document has been submitted once or twice.

(And if it is once, this answer is utterly wrong.)

Comment: This is wrong, the form is submitted **after** the onclick event.

Comment: The order differs, but does the logic do ? I mean, the onclick event and the form submit still (in this case) both submit the form?